# How to sort Excel pivot rows based on information from more columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created an Excel (2013) Pivot table based on an outlook calendar reminders extract.

**See image here:**

[image]

Main columns are Subject, recurring (Y/N), Start Date, etc. (see the file https://gofile.io/?c=3xvJPT).

Pivot does a sorting based on the Subject (rows) but I need to sort it by the start Date (from column C to column L).
Please note some Subjects occur more than once.

**See image here:**

[image]

I am also trying to have dates (14/05/2019) instead of '1's in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution would be to group Subjects by date as you see in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUYXP.jpg